# Table generated from database table - how to add in £ sign?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following code,

```
<?php
// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} ORDER BY Price");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);


echo "<table width='700px'><tr>";

// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);


?>
```

There is a "Price" column where I need the £ sign inserted before each price before it is displayed. I have the HTML code `&#163;` and `&pound;` , however I am not sure where one would insert that to add it before to only the records coming from the Price column.

Comment: Not quite sure how you want it but why don't you just do a check `if($field->name === 'price'){echo "&#163; ".$field->name;}else{echo $field->name;}`

Comment: Save yourself future problems and replace `SELECT *` and `foreach($row as $cell)` with a proper column listing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead, you can do in your foreach:

```
foreach($row as $name => $value)
{
    if($name == 'price')
        echo ...;
    else
        echo ...;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you retrieve values with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. That way you will obtain an associative arrays and you can do this:

```
foreach($row as $cell_name => $cell_value){
}
```

Note: this will only work if you don't have duplicate names in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend rewritting to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_row -> therefore You know when `price` (and other column)s is being processed:

```
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    // $row is associative array...
    echo "<td>$result['id']</td>";
    echo "<td>$result['name']</td>";
    ...
    echo "<td>&pound; $result['price']</td>";
    ...
echo "</tr>\n";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could get the key of the column by doing this:

```
foreach($row as $key => $cell){
    if($key == "Price"){
        echo "<td>&pound; $cell</td>"; //From price column
    }else{
        echo "<td>$cell</td>"; //From other columns
    }
}
```

**Edit: if you want to check that it's printing at the right column:**

```
foreach($row as $key => $cell){
    if($key == "Price"){
        echo "<td>$key: &pound; $cell</td>"; //From price column
    }else{
        echo "<td>$key: $cell</td>"; //From other columns
    }
}
```

Now it will output the name of the column so you will see which column contains the right information. Then when you found the right information just replace "Price" in the if-statement to the right one and then remove $key from the echo.

Comment: Nice! - excuse me to stupid question, but which code would that replace ? I am guessing all of the code for "//printing table rows" after the echo "tr" element ?

Comment: The code withing the while loop where you have your foreach loop. Just after "// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element // of $row to $cell variable". If you look at the code you submitted after those comments and my answer you will see the difference :)

Comment: oh yes! - I've put in, but now a £ sign is going in the retailer column instead :S is the if statement not working ?

Comment: The if statement checks whether the column currently being printed is the column "Price". Look at my edit to be sure it's the right column.

Comment: Ah I see, I got it to work. Your edit of course printed the keys, therefore I was able to check if the key was "1:" which was the Price column, so changed the if statement accordingly. Its now doing what I want! - Thanks!